# How to comunicate from a controller to a directive template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was thinking to pass data from my controller to a directive template. How can I do this?

Here is my controller:

```
$scope.$on('itemSelectedEvent', function (event, args) {
    $scope.displayOrgs.push(data.orgName);
})
```

And the directive:

```
directive('search', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {    
            selecteditemslist: "=",
            searchid: "@",
            selecteditemsdisplay: "=",
            searchobj: '@',
            displayOrgs: '=displayOrgs'    
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs, index, searchobj,searchid) {
            scope.$emit('itemSelectedEvent', {
                selectedId:scope.selectedId,
                sortOrder:index,
                searchId : searchid
            }
        );
    }
});
```

This `displayOrgs` should pass to directive. How is it I am getting undefined?

```
<li class="tag" ng-repeat="list in displayOrgs  track by $index"  ng-class="{selected: $index==selectedIndex}" >
    <span class="tag-label">{{list}}</span>
    <span class="tag-cross pointer" ng-click="Delete($index,selecteditemslist[$index],list,searchobj)">x</span>
</li>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: add the code for the directive

Comment: Instead of doing `$emit` why not just write to `scope.DisplayOrgs` directly since there is already a data binding there by the `scope` property

Comment: solution 1 : the directive share the entiere scope of the controller //
solution 2 : the directive has its own scope (recommended), and retrieve needed data as args

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to generate an event `scope.$emit` to notify controller that variable has got changed.  While you have control over the variables with two binding inside its isolate `scope: { .. }`

> `displayOrgs: '=displayOrgs'` has `=` means two way binding with variable associated with directive
>   element attribute div.

As you are using `displayOrgs: '=displayOrgs'` (in isolated scope) in your directive, the changes in any of the variable of the which is mentioned in isolated scope, that will change automatically in applies those changes to scope variable which is associated with `display-orgs` attribute.

```
link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
   scope.displayOrgs.push(data.orgName); // this will update binding with parent scope.
});
```